# Unhandled event loop exception on a clean Java EE Kepler install on Windows

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-kepler

Quite a few people in our dev team (size 20ish java devs) are experiencing the seemingly well-known "Unhandled event loop exception" when we click between editors and other panes within the Eclipse window. Some people have had some success by installing the WindowBuilder plugin and setting the WB editor as their default editor for Java files, but most of us still get the error regularly. It doesn't seem memory related because you can get it straight away after a cold boot; i.e. it doesn't "work for a while". I think it's likely video-related, because we also get similar video glitch symptoms that have been reported by others, e.g. tab names disappearing until you hover over them etc.

Our video card (most of us I think) is AMD Radeon HD 6450 and we're running 64-bit Windows 7. I've tried shutting down various processes that sound related to the video card, but to no avail.

The error is reproducible on a brand new standard Eclipse J2EE install.

I've searched a lot on this because it affects our day-to-day work so much, but I can't find a solution. Is there something I'm not doing that could workaround this?

Here's my [eclipse config](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-QHmo7MUgGaQ0V3aDQ0THpQM28/edit?usp=sharing) exported.

And as requested, here's the [stack trace](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Ew_V8BB_96WBoLcmbq4QFbzAQznxJFDWpYnOYflx5f4/edit?usp=sharing) from the Error Log. I've also pasted the Session Data at the top of that one.  BTW, the system is running a Core I7 3.4ghz CPU, and I have 16gb ram.

eclipse.buildId=4.3.0.M20130911-1000
java.version=1.7.0_51
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_AU
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4423)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4312)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4283)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:472)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.createHandle(Control.java:704)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label.createHandle(Label.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.createWidget(Control.java:744)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.(Control.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label.(Label.java:101)

Comment: You need to post the stack trace. It will be in the error log view.

Comment: Edited question as per request.

Comment: Well, the 'out of Handles' is an indication that SWT has run out of system resources. Do you have anything particularly heavy in its use of SWT resources (Images, Fonts, Colors...) ? Your comment about using WindowBuilder as the default editor is almost certainly not going to help as it's much more resource intensive than the regular Java editor IMO.

Comment: If possible could you attach a screen shot showing the state of the UI when you encounter this ?